# SonarQube, jump statements in finally block (squid:S1143)

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-catch-finally, sonarlint, false-positive

I know, jump statements in finally block should not be used. In this simple example 'break' is used to break the 'switch'. SonarQube (5.6.3) with 
sonar-java 4.5.0.8398 reports an issue on:

"Jump statements should not occur in "finally" blocks (squid:S1143)"

```
public static void breakInFinallyIssue(){
    int a = 0;
    try{
        a = 1 / 0;
    }catch(Exception x){
        System.out.println("div by zero");
    }
    finally{
        switch (a) {
        case 0:
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        //do something more
    }
}
```

Is this a known FP/bug?

Comment: `finally` is for cleanup. It looks like you've got too much going on there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sometimes there is a lot to clean. Do you think it makes the code too complex for a deeper analysis by sonar? Then it might be a bug. Even this small example causes sonar to report an issue. It seems that any occurrence of 'break' in the finally-block, even when it doesn't cause a jump to somewhere outside the block, causes the issue.

Comment: I consider the presence of the `switch` in the `finally` block a code smell that could easily create a bug, yes. Is it necessarily a bug? No. But why do you need it?

Comment: I agree, this is bad practice. I found a similar constellation in very old production code. I need to know if "Jump statements should not occur in "finally" blocks means that no 'break' ever must occur (in a finally block) "no matter why"? Maybe it is just the rule description that needs a further explanation.Otherwise it looks like a false positive or bug.

Comment: Wait, you don't mean a bug in the tool, do you? No, it isn't a bug in the tool. The tool is reporting as it's configured to report. It's not a bug in the tool when it's doing what it's told. If there is a bug, it's in something you or your team did.

Comment: Yes I mean a bug in the tool. It doesn't tell why this constellation should be replaced. It says "no 'break' in finally". This is definitely wrong. A 'break' that causes the code to leave the block is a bug, a break that causes a switch or do-while to discontinue is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that this is a false positive. However such complex logic doesn't belong to the finally block, and if possible should be extracted to aptly named cleanup method. This will not only shutdown the warning, but also improve readability of your code.

Comment: I created ticket to handle the false positive in future version of the SonarJava analyzer. You can follow development here https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2149